# org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

```
package Tranquility.abc;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class testsensortry {
    public WebDriver driver=null;
    @BeforeMethod
    public void initial() {
        
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:\\Selenium\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://tranquility-management.azurewebsites.net/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2F");
    }
    
 
    @Test
    public void sensor() { 
        driver.findElement(By.id("Email")).sendKeys("admin@gmail.com");
        driver.findElement(By.id("Password")).sendKeys("Admin@123");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Log in']")).click();
        WebElement sesnordrp = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@class='nav navbar-nav navbar-left']/li[2]"));
        Actions act=new Actions(driver);
        act.moveToElement(sesnordrp).build().perform();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@class='nav navbar-nav navbar-left']/li[2]/ul/li[3]")).click();
        WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//a[@class='chosen-single'][1]")));
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='chosen-single'][1]")).click();
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("HospitalID")));
        WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.id("HospitalID"));  
        Select sel=new Select(elem);
        sel.selectByVisibleText("Columbia Asia Hospital");
        
    }

}
```

Filter By Nursing Home: 
            Select Nursing Home
    Apollo Gleneagles
    Apollo Health
    Columbia Asia Hospital
    Global hospital
    Global Test
    Gujar Hospital 2 
    Hospital 1
    Hospital 2
    Hospital 2-A
    KEM Nursing Home
    Nursing 4912 
    Nursing Home 1 name
    Rane Hospital
    reddy test
    Ruby Hall Clinic
    Sahyadri Hospital
    test
    Test 
    test hospital
    Test Nursing Home
    
      Select Nursing Home
      
    
    
      
        
      
      
    `enter code here`

Comment: What code line gives that error?

Comment: WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.id("HospitalID"));
This line

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```java
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("HospitalID")));
```

Try using

```java
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("HospitalID")));
```

In case this still will not work try using Actions move

```java
WebElement elem wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("HospitalID")));
act.moveToElement(elem).build().perform();
```

**UPD**
From your comment I see there is some dropdown that should be opened before accessing this element.
So normally you should open it, this should make this element visible.
You still can click this element with the JavaScript as following, but this is not recommended

```java
WebElement elem = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("HospitalID")));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", elem);
```

Comment: Tried both but not working, now error is:
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.id: HospitalID (tried for 30 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)

Comment: The dropdown I am trying to access is having a text box in it. so that user can enter keywords and search the required options.
Do we have any another option to handle such dropdowns?

Comment: Well, this means (I guess) you do not actually open that dropdown. What command opens that dropdown?

Comment: Below step opens dropdown:
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='chosen-single'][1]")).click();
Once I open the dropdown there is a text field to enter keywords and below that all dropdown options are present by default. when I enter any word in that textbox dropdown options are sorting according to keyword.

Comment: Does this dropdown actually open with your selenium code?

Comment: I have tried key chords to enter those words and then press ENTER to select the option but I am not finding any way to directly select an option without entering text

Comment: can you share a link to that page?

Comment: sorry due to security reasons I cant share that project link. :(

Comment: I understand. Have you tried JS executor?

Comment: JS executor is working but it's selecting 1st value by default. unable to select 3rd or 4rth value from dropdwon

Comment: I guess you should update the `driver.findElement(By.id("HospitalID"));` selector for that